# Ethereum private network - What is AWS minimum hardware requirement?

Tags: mining, ether, hardware, aws

I have been setting up private blockchain network on two AWS EC2 instances for one of the demo setup. Initially, I chose t2.micro for both. However, miner.start(1) has been very unpredictable so far.

I dont see number of calls will me huge so may be 20-25 transactions on these nodes during demo after the initial setup, which will be done beforehand.

I aim to take t2.medium now. However not sure, if it is sufficient still. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The t2 instances have burstable CPU allocations.

Both Geth and Parity are relatively CPU intensive, and as such I would suggest one of the M3/M4 instances being most appropriate.

I use Linode for my nodes because they have more cost effective options for playing around with your setup.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. It helps, I am rebuilding my machine with M4 now.